# Не работает в replace замена пробела

Tags: python

```
string = input()
string.replace(" ","")
print(len(string))
```

ввожу строку `раз два три` и должен выдать ответ 9(не считая пробелы) а выдает 11

хотя по идее в `replace`  прописал , чтобы пробелы удаляло

Comment: Вы никуда не сохраняете значение, которое возвращает replace. В переменной string остаётся лежать старая строка с пробелами

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`replace` не изменяет строку, а создаёт новую, поэтому её надо сохранить

```
string = input()
string = string.replace(" ","")
print(len(string))
```